# Error in PDKPin.m for Pinterest iOS SDK

Tags: ios, pinterest

I am currently using the iOS SDK's "getAuthenticatedUserPinsWithFields" method to return a user's pins:

```
let fields = ["id","note","url","image"] as NSSet
PDKClient.sharedInstance().getAuthenticatedUserPinsWithFields(fields as Set<NSObject>,
        success: { (responseObject :PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in
```

I believe I traced the error to PDKPin.m initWithDictionary:

```
(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
self = [super initWithDictionary:dictionary];
if (self) {

//  _url = [NSURL URLWithString:dictionary[@"link"]];
    _url = [NSURL URLWithString:dictionary[@"url"]];

    _descriptionText = dictionary[@"note"];
    _board = [PDKBoard boardFromDictionary:dictionary[@"board"]];
    _creator = [PDKUser userFromDictionary:dictionary[@"creator"]];
    _metaData = dictionary[@"metadata"];

    _repins = [self.counts[@"repins"] unsignedIntegerValue];
    _likes = [self.counts[@"likes"] unsignedIntegerValue];
    _comments = [self.counts[@"comments"] unsignedIntegerValue];
}
return self;
}
```

The @"link" reference always returns nil but using "url" will return the url to the pin. Is the SDK wrong in this case?

Thanks, Anita

Comment: Any luck with this Anita?  I have the same issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474573/pinterest-sdk-how-to-get-a-pdkpins-link

Comment: I believe the SDK is in error still and probably should have an issue written against the problem. I got around it temporarily by making the modification locally as described above. I will check back later when I have some time.

Comment: Thanks, I did submit an issue on the repo, I am trying to get the Pin's link (i.e. website the pin links to)